# Only toggle nearest DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

Trying to have it so that when you hit the +/- icon only the closest div toggles open/close. Currently all the DIVs will toggle...I tried using `$(this).siblings` to fix it but must be doing something wrong since it is not working.

Here is my runnable code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show-less').on('click', function() {
    $('.report-detail-section').toggle('fast');
    $('.show-less-icon').slideToggle(0);
    $('.show-more-icon').slideToggle(0);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  width: 500px;
}
body h4 {
  background: #555;
  margin: 0;
}
a.show-less {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.report-detail-section {
  background: #F0F0F0;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4><a class="show-less">Step 1: Report Info 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus show-less-icon pull-right" aria-hidden="true" style="display:inline;" title="Hide Section Details"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus show-more-icon pull-right" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" title="Show Section Details"></span></a>
</h4>
<div class="report-detail-section" style="display: block;">
  Report Summary Content
</div>

<h4><a class="show-less">Step 2: Data Selection 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus show-less-icon pull-right" aria-hidden="true" style="display:inline;" title="Hide Section Details"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus show-more-icon pull-right" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" title="Show Section Details"></span></a>
</h4>
<div class="report-detail-section" style="display: block;">
  Report Summary Content
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show-less').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().next('.report-detail-section').toggle('fast');
        $(this).find('span').slideToggle(0);
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cw4vp7s3/2/)**

In your click handler `$('.report-detail-section')` will select all elements of that class. By using `$(this).parent().next('.report-detail-section')` instead, you target the `.report-detail-section` element *relative* to the one being clicked on.

Comment: I went with this option, even though I prefer granular control for the <span> $('.show-less-icon',this).slideToggle(0); $('.show-more-icon',this).slideToggle(0);

Answer (score 1):

You are toggling all the elements that have the 'report-detail-section' class. Instead replace

```
$('.report-detail-section').toggle('fast');
```

with

```
$(this).parent().next('.report-detail-section').toggle('fast');
```

**or**

```
$(this).closest('h4').next('.report-detail-section').toggle('fast');
```

Using the context here makes sure that you are selecting the right element which would be toggled.

Also @showdev mentioned, it is a better idea to provide a context for the other elements as well as multiple elements can have the same class.

This works provided all your HTML follows the same structure.

[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cw4vp7s3/5/)

Also cache the jQuery selectors whenever possible. It does not matter in this case, but when you get to too many selections in your application.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show-less').on('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parent().next('.report-detail-section').toggle('fast');
        $('.show-less-icon, .show-more-icon', $this).slideToggle(0);
    });
});
```

Comment: I also suggest `$('.show-less-icon',this).slideToggle(0); $('.show-more-icon',this).slideToggle(0);` for the icon elements.

Comment: Thanks, that did it...for future reference here is the updated working Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cw4vp7s3/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show-less').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest("h4").next('.report-detail-section').toggle('fast');
        $(this).find('.show-less-icon').slideToggle(0);
        $(this).find('.show-more-icon').slideToggle(0);
    });
});
```

Comment: This toggles both icons at once. I suggest `$('.show-less-icon',this).slideToggle(0); $('.show-more-icon',this).slideToggle(0);` for the icon elements.